# Loop through enumeration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, enums

What is best way to loop through an enumeration looking for a matching value?

```
string match = "A";

enum Sample { A, B, C, D }

foreach(...) {
  //should return Sample.A
}
```

Comment: foreach what? What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm looking to see if "A" exists and return the matching enumerator value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx):

```
Sample e = (Sample)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sample), match);
```

You can loop through the values by calling [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) or [`Enum.GetNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Sample matchStringToSample(string match)
{
    return (Sample)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sample), match);
}
```

You'd have to handle the case where the string match is not a valid enum value. `Enum.Parse` throws an `ArgumentException` in that case.

Comment: If you expect it to fail sometimes, use Enum.TryParse()

Comment: @Nelson: `Enum.TryParse` is new to .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(Sample), "A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

```
(Sample)Enum.Parse(typeof(Samples), "A"); //returns Sample.A
```

Comment: @Mark Byers, it is just an example statement. Give him a break.